# Замена текста, регулярное выражение. Как правильно?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, notepad++

Есть текст: `abc:ABCD`
Нужно чтобы получилось так: `abc:aBCD`
Поиск делаю вот такой регуляркой: `(^.*)([:|;])([A-Z]+)$`

Замену на что нужно сделать, чтобы первая буква была меленькой, а последующие КАПСОМ?

Вот строка для примера: `test0000@test.ru:TEST`
Должно получится так: `test0000@test.ru:tEST`
Строки постоянно разные будут!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28247301/4928642

Comment: `^(.*[:;])([A-Z])([A-Z]*)$` => `$1\L$2\U$3`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, кстати, а в NPP есть разница между `\1` и `$1` в строке замены?

Comment: Да, бывает, но чтобы это увидеть, нужно очень постараться.

Comment: Что-то не хочет работать... 
https://regexr.com/4hfua

Comment: А причём тут regexr, если Notepad++ в тегах? Если вы собираетесь использовать выражение в Notepad++, там и используйте.

Answer (score 1):

Сервис regexr поддерживает две "разновидности" регулярных выражений: JavaScript (ECMAScript) и PCRE:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В Notepad++ поддержка регулярных выражений реализована с помощью библиотеки [Boost](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax/perl_syntax.html). Она хоть и очень похожа на PCRE, всё-таки отличается от неё. Операторы замены регистра `\l`, `\u`, `\U` (`\U...\E`) и `\L` (`\L...\E`) поддерживаются именно в Boost, но не в PCRE.

Используйте

**Найти**:       `^(.*[:;])([A-Z])([A-Z]*)$`
**Заменить**: `$1\L$2\U$3`

**Подробности**

- `^` -
- `(.*[:;])` - Подмаска №1: 0 и более любых символов, отличных от символов перехода на новую строку, как можно больше, а затем двоеточие или точка с запятой
- `([A-Z])` - Подмаска №2: одна заглавная буква ASCII
- `([A-Z]*)` - Подмаска №3: 0 и более заглавных букв ASCII
- `$` - конец строки.

Шаблон замены `$1\L$2\U$3` вставит обратно значение первой подмаски (`$1`), значение второй подмаски в нижнем регистре (`\L$2`) и содержимое третьей подмаски в верхнем регистре (`\U$3`).

Answer (score 0):

Найти:

```
([:;])(\w)(\w*)
```

Заменить на:

```
\1\L\2\U\3
```

[image: скриншот]